# Viewing a single record from a database using a link

Tags: database, codeigniter

I have a link for each record that is displayed on the screen and when i click on the link, I would like to show all the details of the record on a new page.

Basically when i click the link, I get a url with the id no. of that item like:

polls/index.php/user/vote/59

NOw i am trying to display the title and text of that id no.

IN my controller, I have a method to do this:

```
public function display_poll($id=0){

    $this->load->helper('form');  
    $this->load->helper('html'); 
    $this->load->model('polls_model');  

    $data['polls_item'] = $this->polls_model->get($id);

    if (empty($data['polls_item']))
    {
        show_404();
    }

    $this->load->helper('html');
    $data['content'] = $this->load->view('user/view', $data, TRUE);
    $data['id'] = $data['polls_item']['id'];
    $data['title'] = $data['polls_item']['title'];
    $data['text'] = $data['polls_item']['text'];

    $this->load->view('user/vote',$data);   

}
```

IN my view, I am doing it like this:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <h2>Voting Page:</h2>

<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url();?>js/jquery.js"></script>      
</head>

<body>

<?php echo form_open('user/vote'); ?>
<?php echo form_hidden($polls_item['id']); ?>
<?php echo $polls_item['title'] ?>
<?php echo $polls_item['text'] ?>

<?php echo form_close(); ?>


</body>

</html>
```

and in my model, I have a function like this:

```
function get($id)
{
    $query = $this->db->get_where('polls', array('id'=>$id));
    return $query->row_array();       
}
```

I am getting this sort of error:

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined variable: polls_item

Filename: user/vote.php

Line Number: 27

How can i fix this? YOur help will be greatly appreciated.
THankyou.

Comment: why don't you just access it with $id, since you are setting it in the controller. **$data['id'] = $data['polls_item']['id'];**

Answer (score 0):

i'm not sure why you get this but try

```
 var_dump($polls_item) ;
```

in your view and

```
var_dump($data['polls_item']);
```

your controller before calling the view

Answer (score 0):

URL

```
polls/index.php/user/vote/59
```

Controller

```
public function display_poll()
{
    $this->load->helper('form');  
    $this->load->helper('url'); 
    $this->load->helper('html'); 
    $this->load->model('polls_model');  

    $this->uri->segment(3,0); // 0 means default
    $polls_item = $this->polls_model->get($id);

    if (empty($data['polls_item']))
    {
        show_404();
    }
    $data['polls_item'] =   $polls_item;
    $data['content']    =   $this->load->view('user/view', $data, TRUE);
    $data['id']         =   $polls_item['id'];
    $data['title']      =   $polls_item['title'];
    $data['text']       =   $polls_item['text'];

    $this->load->view('user/vote',$data);   
}
```

Comment: hmm still get the same error.. Is there something im doing wrong?

Comment: fixed it!! SIlly one line of code in my index.php " echo "<td>". anchor('user/display_poll/'.$polls_item['id'],'Vote') ."</td>";"